# where to put scraper logic in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, web-scraping

I want to regularly (once a day) **scrape** data and insert into the database table which I want to completely clear before each insertion of the scraped data. Which in turn I want to present with my presentation logic.

I'm not sure how to structure this.

For the presentation logic I guess it's simple, I make a request to a controller to get all data from the DB, and then I just present it with views.

For the **scraper** logic, I'm not so sure..
Since I want to regularly **scrape** (cron job?), I heard about Laravel scheduler, from a tutorial I saw, the logic was put into a command file.. so that's where I should put my php script for the scheduler to run?

Or do I need to create a model and put the logic there, use a controller to insert it into the DB?
If so, how do I schedule it as a cron job?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you planning on being able to run the scrape manually as well as it being automated?

Comment: only for testing I will run it one time manually so I can build upon it the presentation logic. When I push to production I want it to recreate the database table once a day with the fresh data it scraps.

Comment: FYI it's __scraper__ (and __scraping__, __scraped__, __scrape__) not scrapper

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Why not write a service for this and use that service from your scheduler?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should use an [artisan command](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/artisan#writing-commands) which contains the logic for scraping (or calls a service which contains that logic). That command can then be run either manually or via [the scheduler](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling#scheduling-artisan-commands) which should be called via a cronjob.